# Can I use critical hits under the effect of "Greenskins Invade"?

Tags: chaos-in-the-old-world

There is the Old World card "Greenskins Invade". It states

> While this Old World card remains in play, each player battling in a region containing an Event token may roll only one battle die, in total, per battle phase.

It's clear that no matter how many dice I could use in the battle phase, I can only use one of them in this region. But what if I roll a critical (6)? Can I reroll the die because I'm using the same die (so the count of the total dice used doesn't change), or does it count as using a different die?

Comment: @ikegami: I'm pretty sure that it's the correct answer. if you posted it as an answer, then I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one rolls a 6, the die isn't technically re-rolled. According to the rulebook, the rolling a 6 causes an additional die to be rolled.

> In addition, every result of 6 EXPLODES, which means that the attacker rolls one additional battle die immediately (which causes an additional hit on a 4, 5, or 6, and which explodes again on a 6).

Which makes it clear that if the Old World card limits my dice to one, then I wouldn't be able to roll an additional die even if it would explode.